# How to call static block into plugin Processor php file in magento2

Tags: magento2, static-block, plugin

How to call the static block into magento2 plugin processor php file.

thanks

Comment: What is your complete requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I followed like this I got an answer.

```
$shippingMessage = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('shipping_note/shipping_note/shippingnote',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['country_id']['notice'] = $shippingMessage;
```

Thanks